# Multiple intervals in PHP - return last continued item

Tags: php, date

I have multiple intervals in PHP and I want to know what is maximum end_date in continuing intervals.

Example 1 (we have 3 intervals):

```
start_date - end_date
2017-01-01 - 2018-01-01
2018-01-01 - 2019-01-01
2019-02-01 - 2020-02-01
```

Result of function is 2019-01-01, because our date continues to there. Then  there is 1 month gap.

Example 2 (5 intervals):

```
start_date - end_date
2017-01-01 - 2017-02-01
2017-01-05 - 2017-01-10
2017-01-30 - 2017-02-05
2017-02-03 - 2017-02-04
2017-02-08 - 2017-02-12
```

Result here is 2017-02-05

I am not sure if there is some helpfull function for this. I was trying to search like intervals or something like that without any solution.

Thank you for any clues.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: That's why I ask - I am looking for some php fuction which could be helpfull for this.

Comment: I think you did not understand my question.

Comment: what is answer of first example `2019-01-01` or `2020-02-01`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find anything helpfull in PHP or any clue for this anywhere, so I program it myself:

```
<?php
$example1 = [
    ['start' => '2017-01-01', 'end' => '2018-01-01'],
    ['start' => '2018-01-01', 'end' => '2019-01-01'],
    ['start' => '2019-02-01', 'end' => '2020-02-01']
];

$example2 = [
    ['start' => '2017-01-01', 'end' => '2017-02-01'],
    ['start' => '2017-01-05', 'end' => '2017-01-10'],
    ['start' => '2017-01-30', 'end' => '2017-02-05'],
    ['start' => '2017-02-03', 'end' => '2017-02-04'],
    ['start' => '2017-02-08', 'end' => '2017-02-12']
];


// @param intervals are ordered by start date
function getMaxContinuingEndDate($intervals)
{

    if (empty($intervals)) return NULL;

    $result = ['start' => $intervals[0]['start'], 'end' => $intervals[0]['end']];

    foreach($intervals as $interval) {
        if ($interval['start'] <= $result['start'] && $interval['end'] >= $result['start']) {
            $result['start'] = $interval['start'];
        }

        if ($interval['end'] >= $result['end'] && $interval['start'] <= $result['end']) {
            $result['end'] = $interval['end'];
        }
    }

    return $result['end'];
}


echo getMaxContinuingEndDate($example1);
echo "\n";
echo getMaxContinuingEndDate($example2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`date_diff()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
```